# How to make a combination of smooth lines and one straight line in a combo chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=d6fd6426f4f93a21e2ef806a2a88e6cc0576434e
Please check the link above. I want to make the last column labeled "mud weight" a straight line and keep the other lines smooth but I always get either straight or smooth for all the lines.

```
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

  function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['depth', 'pore pressure', 'pore +SM', 'frac. pressure', 'frac. -SM', 'mud weight'],
      [10500,  9.75,      10.25,         16.95,             16.45,           12],
      [11100,  11.5,      12,         17.35,             16.85,           12],
      [11099,  11.5,      12,         17.35,             16.85,           16.85],
      [12000,  15,      15.5,         17.8,             17.2,           16.85],
      [13000,  16,      16.5,         18.1,             17.6,           16.85],
      [14000,  16.35,      16.85,        18.4,             17.9,          16.85],
      [13999,  16.35,      16.85,        18.4,             17.9,          17.9],
      [16000,  16.8,      17.3,        18.7,             18.2,           17.9],
      [18000,  17.2,      17.7,        18.9,             18.4,           17.9],
      [19000,  17.4,      17.9,         19,             18.5,          17.9]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    ac.draw(data, {
      title : 'pore pressure and fracture pressure',
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      vAxis: {title: "Cups",direction:-1},
      hAxis: {title: "Month"},
      orientation: 'vertical',
      seriesType: "line",
      'smoothLine': true,
      series: {5: {type: "line",'smoothLine': false}}
    });
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

---

```
 <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `'smoothLine':true/false` you should use `curveType:'function'/'none'`.

Also you are indexing that series incorrectly - the series are zero-indexed, but your `depth` column doesn't count towards this indexing, so the `mud weight` series is actually index 4.

Here is the updated code which should replace your `ac.draw(data, {...})`:

```
ac.draw(data, {
  title : 'pore pressure and fracture pressure',
  width: 600,
  height: 400,
  vAxis: {title: "Cups",direction:-1},
  hAxis: {title: "Month"},
  orientation: 'vertical',
  seriesType: "line",
  curveType: 'function',
  series: {4: {curveType: 'none'}}
});
```